# How can I get php 8.1 and integrate a web server for nano node?

Tags: server, 20.04, php

My aim is to run [nano node monitor cli](https://github.com/NanoTools/nanoNodeMonitor), and I am really confused.

Node fetches the ledger files (2nd day now) and seems to work with Docker, but no monitoring is possible unless I get some help to configure their settings correctly and download the proper software.